# Accessing PyQt4 UI elements from other functions referenced from another module

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm using PyQt4 using Qt designer. This is the first time I've used it so I'm just getting my head round a few things but this has me stumped.

The problem I'm having is that once the UI window has been defined and created, I try to call a function to update a UI element and it produces a "not defined" error.

However, if I place the same code in the block of code where the element is initially defined, it works fine.

I have written an example below to show what I mean more clearly.

The problem is I need to call to update the lcd number from a different module which contains a function that is called when a button is clicked.

To show this, I've made a form with an lcdnumber (lcd1) and a pushbutton (button1) in qtdesigner, compiled the code in the file "testui.py", which creates the class "MainWindow".

In a.py, I have put:

```
import testui as interface
import sys
import b
from PyQt4 import QtCore,  QtGui

ui= interface.Ui_MainWindow()

def updateui():
   for i in range(0, 100):
       ui.lcd1.setProperty("value", i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   test = QtGui.QMainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(test)
   ui.lcd1.setProperty("value", 1)
   ui.button1.clicked.connect(b.updatelcd)
   test.show()
   app.exec_()
```

This opens the window, and sets the initial state and connects the button to a function in b.py.

In b.py, I have put:

```
from a import updateui

def updatelcd():
   updateui()
```

When I click the button this calls the function in a.py, which leads to the error:

"Module has no attribute lcd1"

This has been confusing me for a while because ui.lcd1.setProperty works in the **main** loop!

It must be something fundamentally wrong with what I'm doing but I can't work it out.

Any ideas appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You are doing circular imports? Why?

Comment: I have a function in another module which reads data from a serial port. I would like to update the lcd with a value from the serial port on click of the button which, additionally, closes the port; I'm trying to keep the serial interfacing and ui seperate.

Comment: Problem solved using classes - see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing kind of circular imports which is by itself not a very good idea.

What happens here is:
When you import a's `updateui` the ui variable is not imported to be.
The ui variable may be gloabal, but only in your a module.
So when you call the function `updatelcd` in `b` which calls `updateui` that was imported from `a` you get a `NameError` for `lcd1` because ui was not initialized.

Actually I am not that sure why it does not complain about ui in the first place. It might be that python imported the knowledge that there was a global variable ui defined in a.

Instead of just importing the function 'updateui`from`a`in`b`and including`b`in`a` you should think about how you could achieve your goal without circular imports.

You should think about not only having modules but also classes. Make it object oriented. 
So what you could do:
1. Create a class in your b-module which does everything the way your module does now.
2. Make a constructor that takes the `interface.Ui_MainWindow()` as an argument and stores it.
3. On this you will then tater be able to do your updatelcd(without going to any methods defined in a)
4. Create an instance of your b-class in your a-module. On this instance you can call your function that updates the lcd.

This is what code for your b-class could look like

```
class B:
  __init__(self, mainWindow):
    self.mainWindow = mainWindow

  def updatelcd(self):
    for i in range(0, 100):
      self.mainWindow.lcd1.setProperty("value", i)
```

So module a will look something like this:

```
import testui as interface
import sys
import b
from PyQt4 import QtCore,  QtGui

ui= interface.Ui_MainWindow()
thing = b.B(ui) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 test = QtGui.QMainWindow()
 ui.setupUi(test)
 ui.lcd1.setProperty("value", 1)
 ui.button1.clicked.connect(thing.updatelcd())
 test.show()
 app.exec_()
```

Comment: OK thanks. So I would need to reinitialise ui locally in the updateui() function? I'm kind of thinking I should completly redesign and put the UI definitions in the same module as the functions I want to run on the UI elements; might that be a better solution?

Comment: You can put them in the same module, or you create a class, instantiate it and have that in your module, to call when you need it.

Comment: Thanks, thats a helpful example. I'll give that a go in my main programme.

Comment: Got it working; I now have a "serialinterface" class that takes the ui as a parameter and can update the lcd with it without importing the module. Thanks for your help! Guess i need to think more OO...